# populate table from one to another

Tags: mysql

I would like to copy data from an existing table say table1 to a new table table2.  The tables' engines are different. I mean, the existing table uses MyISAM and the new one uses Innodb.

Comment: Look at this http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,26193,190902#msg-190902

Comment: Another MyISAM to InnoDB article. http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/46370

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`insert into NewTable (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from OldTable`

Answer (score 6):

```sql
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

[INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: the engines are irrelevant, it will work. you can even setup replication to different engines.